# QuickBooks php XML Responce parsing Error

Tags: php, class, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I am using ***QuickBooks v3 php sdk 2.1.0***.

Running a query (`SELECT * FROM SalesReceipts`) gives the XML Response but getting NULL value, tried to applying error message and got this error

﻿﻿**Class com\intuit\schema\finance\v3\IPPid does not exist.**

Any Solutions ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> At Last Found the Solution....

Steps:

1. Download the fresh sdk
2. Replace All the files in sdk/Data Folder
3. Test Your code now!

If error still persist, replace all the files excepts sdk.config and this will fix your issues.